# Does Terraform batch resource creation automatically?

Tags: terraform

So I was applying a TF Provider to create 150 resource via simple `terraform apply` and noticed that it prints out resources in batches:

```
# batch #1
foo_resource.bar_1: Creating...
...
foo_resource.bar_10: Creating...
foo_resource.bar_1: Creation complete after 12s [id=...]
...
foo_resource.bar_10: Creation complete after 15s [id=...]
# batch #2
foo_resource.bar_11: Creating...
...
```

Moreover when I opened trace logs I could see that there're 10 logs within the same second:

```
# batch #1
2022-03-03T00:48:59.139-0800 [INFO]  provider.: 2022/03/03 00:48:59 [DEBUG] Created foo_1: timestamp=2022-03-03T00:48:59.139-0800
2022-03-03T00:48:59.139-0800 [INFO]  provider.: 2022/03/03 00:48:59 [DEBUG] Created foo_3: timestamp=2022-03-03T00:48:59.139-0800
...
# batch #2
2022-03-03T00:49:20.866-0800 [INFO]  provider.: 2022/03/03 00:49:20 [DEBUG] Created foo_12: timestamp=2022-03-03T00:49:10.866-0800
```

so you can clearly see timestamp difference between batch #1 and batch #2 is about `20` seconds (00:49:20 - 00:48:59) which is the exact same timeout that provider uses internally after creating each resource so it seems like it doesn't send `150` create requests simulteniously but rather execute them in batches where each batch size is `10`.

The question is does Terraform batch resource creation automatically or it's just a coincidence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terraform doesn't perform batching, but does have a parallelism limit, which defaults to 10: https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/apply#parallelism-n